# Writing a directive to encapsulate multiple directives Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular 1.x and I have a section of code that I'm looking to repeat quite a bit, so I wanna throw it in a directive. The trouble is, it's somewhat complicated and I'm not sure how to begin writing it.

Essentially, it's a section of the page that displays various card directive and with infinite scrolling and perfect scrollbar.

```
<perfect-scrollbar refresh-on-change="myScope.data">
   <div class="limit-columns">
      <masonry masonry-options="{gutter: 30, isFitWidth: true}">
           <user-card class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="item in myScope.data"></user-card>
      </masonry>
      <div class="infinite-scroller" infinite-scroll="myScope.showMore()" infinite-scroll-tolerance="5"></div>
   </div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Perfect-scrollbar and masonry are both angular libraries on GitHub. Infinite-scroller is one I wrote myself, but works as you'd expect.

`myScope` contains a `data` attribute that is a list of objects containing a card's data. `myScope.showMore` is a function that adds items to that `myScope.data` list. Perfect-scrollbar also takes the `refresh-on-change` attribute which watches for changes on a particular object, in this case the list.

Ideally my directive would look something like this:

```
<card-scroller gutter="30" tolerance="5">
   <some-card ng-repeat="achievements.data"></some-card>
</card-scroller>
```

But I'm not sure how feasible this is. Thanks!